# How To Check if button is hovered, and output message

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have 40 buttons in a application that I need custom hovers that will show in a status field. I have made a function for adding a certain message and one to remove, so upon a hover, it calls the function, and same with leaving the button.

I want 40 different messages and one way of doing that is to check which button is being hovered over by the mouse.

```
if(button1.hovered == true){
  string message = "scenario1";
}
elseif(button2.hovered == true){
  scenario2...etc
}
```

Is there a way to check if hovered? and check it in a if statement?

ive decided to add more info so it might be easier to get my point.

add message to listview when mouse hoover.

```
    void messAdd(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string now = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy") + " - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
        string message = "message 1";
        found = false;

        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(message);
        foreach (ListViewItem z in listView1.Items)
        {
            if (z.Text == message)
            { found = true; }
        }

        if (found == false)
        {
            item.SubItems.Add(now.ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
            listView1.EnsureVisible(item.Index);
        }
        else
        {
            DeleteIfNecessary(message);
        }
    }
```

delete message from listbox when mouse leave:

```
    void messdel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string message = "message 1";
        found = false;

        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(message);
        foreach (ListViewItem z in listView1.Items)
        {
            if (z.Text == message)
            { found = true; }
        }

        if (found == true)
        {
            DeleteIfNecessary(message);
        }

    }
```

I can make 4 of these functions for each buttons, but since i need 40 different messages, stupid yes, but there is no way to send a message argument through the function, so i need to use the if test and check witch button is hovered and then output the message to that specified button. and im using visual studio and windows forms, sorry for not mentioned.

Comment: WPF? Winforms? WebForms? Silverlight? WP7? Metro?

Comment: If web forms you could create your own derived Button class which has a HoverMessage property, then attach to the MouseHover event and set the message. (Then undo it in the MouseLeave event)

Comment: sorry for that. winforms im on :)

Comment: Hi there welcome to StackOverflow, there is a hollow checkbox next to answers that will get you points when you tick it. We love questions with a bit of code em in: take Halley's answer, cast the sender into the button that was clicked and then, by the button name work out which function you need to call. ps It helps if you mention that `Please excuse any spelling or grammatical mistakes, English isn't my first language`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `Control.MouseHover` event. You can implement:

```
private void button_MouseHover(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    doSomething(sender);
}
```

and for all of your buttons, set event handler for `MouseHover` to `button_MouseHover` in IDE, or do it in code:

```
this.button1.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.button_MouseHover);
```

By checking the `sender` parameter you can know which button is calling the event handler.

**Update**

According to your update in the question, I think you can just use `messAdd` as the event handler for `MouseEnter` event for all of your buttons, and use `messdel` as the event handler for `MouseLeave`. Again, you don't need to create a copy of these two methods for all of your buttons, you just need to assign the **same** event handler method for all the buttons, and check `sender` to know who is calling the event handler - then creating different messages.

The `sender` is your `Button` object. Just cast it to a `Button` and access what you want (text, tag, name, etc.) to know which `Button` is trying to add/remove message on the list view.

**Update 2**

```
Button button = sender as Button;
if (button == null) {
    // not a button, do nothing
    return;
}

string message = String.Empty;
if (sender.Equals(button1)) {
    message = "message1";
} else if (sender.Equals(button2)) {
    message = "message2";
} ...
```

Comment: i have 4 buttons and it will be alot of code for each button, that why i wana do if tests.and and refer to same function, so i need do if true on all buttons,then do code

Comment: @1244 You don't need a lot of code for each button. The buttons can share a same event handler. Just do different things for different buttons in your event handler by checking who the `sender` is.

Comment: my output messages are describing what buttons do kinda a help for user. so i need difrent mess for each button, so the variable "message"  is kinda difrent, dependig on witch button is hovered.

Comment: @1244 Did you notice the `sender` part?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume this is WinForms, since you didn't specify otherwise.

You can create an int `hoveredId` that represents which button is hovered (value `-1` means nothing is hovered). When creating the buttons, set the Tag property to the button's id number.

Then register each button to both of these functions:

```
private void buttons_MouseEnter(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = ((Button)sender);

    hoveredId = (int)btn.Tag;
}

private void buttons_MouseLeave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = ((Button)sender);

    if ((int)btn.Tag == hoveredId)
        hoveredId = -1;
}
```

When checking which button is hovered, you can use a switch statement:

```
switch (hoveredId)
{
  case 1:
    string message = "scenario1";
    break;
  case 2:
    scenario2...etc
    break;
}
```

Comment: i will try this :) and well see how it goes :)

Comment: Do you want to update the message as soon as the button is hovered?